# when my record is created or updated in line item with the help of trigger same copy of it populate in the stock object

Tags: trigger

I have a query. I have two object both are unrelated name `stock__c(fields:- product name,total no.of pieces)` and `line_item__c (fields:-product name,unit sold)`. what i want is i want to apply trigger on these unrelated object.and want to update total no of pieces by subtracting it by `unit sold value`.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your `line item` and `stock quantity` both must have a lookup to `Product`. That's how you would know which `line item` is related to which product and which `stock quantity` you have to subtract. If you don't have a separate `Product` object you need to create it.(That's how standard SALES cloud work)

You can use standard `Product2` object for your convenience . 
Schema of Stock will be like `Stock__C(ProductLookup,total no of pieces)`
 where as the schema of line item will look something like `Line_item__C(ProductLookup,UnitSold)`.

When a new `lineItem` is created you need to reduce the stock,
When the `qty` in line item is updated you need to update the `stock quantity`,
When whole line item is depleted you need to restore the original `stock quantity`.

This can't be done using standard Salesforce Workflows, Processbuilder in an easy way. But Apex trigger will allow you to simplify this requirement .